# Remove trailing spaces of an array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array. While printing I want to remove the trailing spaces at the end of each row.

```
A = [[ 1,2,3 ,4 ,5],
 [16,17,18,19,6],
 [15,24,25,20,7],
 [14,23,22,21,8],
 [13,12,11,10,9]]

for i in range(len(A)):
    for j in range(len(A)):
        print(A[i][j], end = ' ')
    print()
```

My test case are failing because of trailing space. Can anyone tell me where the mistake is?

Comment: Thats not valid pyhton. Are you using numpy or something? Please create a [mre]. This currently only gives you a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: your J loop operates on the wrong dimension if you do not have a square input - it should be range(len(A[i]) - or better dont index but use iteration of the data itself

Comment: @PatrickArtner modified the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You print your spaces yourself by using

```
print(A[i][j], end= ' ')
               ^^^^^^^^
```

I would suggest doing

```
A = [[ 1,2,3 ,4 ,5],
     [16,17,18,19,6],
     [15,24,25,20,7],
     [14,23,22,21,8],
     [13,12,11,10,9]]

for inner in A:
    print(*inner)
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5
16 17 18 19 6
15 24 25 20 7
14 23 22 21 8
13 12 11 10 9
```

without any trailing spaces.